# Unable to connect to the Netbeans plugin portal

Tags: netbeans-8

I have an error **Unable to connect to the Netbeans plugin portal** when I try to resolve an error in my `Java EJB` application.

I have tried using **no proxy** and **Use system proxy settings** and both didn't work. even when I test my connection it looks fine (can see the green tick)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is currently transitioning to become a top level apache project and they are working on the infrastructure which also includes redirecting some domains. I guess that's the root cause of your problem. You can read the current status [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-17245).